# base_discount_tax_compensation_amount field in the Order, Invoice, and Credit Memo objects of the Rest API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

What is the base_discount_tax_compensation_amount field in the Order, Invoice, and Credit Memo objects of the Rest API in Magento 2.

The only thing it says in the schema is: "The base discount tax compensation amount for a {object type}".

How do I get a non-zero value for this? What type of settings do I need in Magento 2 and what type of order do I need to place to have something other than 0 in this field?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

1. Add a bundle product with two simple products that has different tax classes to the cart.
2. Set all tax settings to "including tax" from the admin